# Exception on CAtlMap.GetNext call C++

Tags: c++, exception

I have a Map which returns object based on Position passed.
What I am actually doing now is retrieve the start position using GetStartPosition and then loop through all the positions with a null check.

```
__POSITION* pos = m_mapofPosBlocksToEmulators.GetStartPosition();
while (pos) {
  Emulator* pEmulator = m_mapOfPosBlocksToEmulators.GetValueAt(pos);
  //do something
  m_mapOfPosBlocksToEmulators.GetNext(pos); //exception thrown here 
}
```

`m_mapOfPosBlocksToEmulators` is of type CAtlMap which contains all objects.

Exception:

> "operation is not allowed when object is closed".

I did a null check before getNext:-

```
if (pos != NULL)
```

but it didn't worked.

I want to know that in which context is that exception is thrown, I mean which object is closed? And what does that mean? Is there any way to check if the object is closed?

If anyone have face same problem then please let me know and also I am kind of newbie to **C++** so anyone want to give any extra insight, I will appreciate that :).

Edit: This exception is thrown when pos value = 0x00000000.

Comment: As stated in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6fwh89e.aspx#catlmap__getnext GetNext() requires a pointer, so you need to use GetNext(&pos).

Comment: Thank you Willy for your answer, and sorry I forgot to mention that pos is already a pointer. Edited the question

Comment: `if ((pos != NULL) == true)` this is a funny way of writing conditions, just write `if (pos != NULL)`